# c++ : pointer to a class instance created in constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers

First, sorry for thw poor title... I don't really know how to express with one
sentance what I mean... You are weclome to edit the title.

I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
class A{
    public:
        A(double a):a_(a){}
    private:
        double a_;
}

class B{
    public
        B():a_ptr_(NULL){}
        B(A const& a):a_ptr_(new A(a)){}
        ~B(){ delete a_ptr_; }
        void set(A const& a){ a_ptr_ = new A(a); }

    private:
        A*  a_ptr_;
}

class C{
    public
        C():a_ptr_(NULL){}
        C(A const& a):a_ptr_(&a){}
        void set(A const& a){ a_ptr_ = &a; }

    private:
        A*  a_ptr_;
}
```

My problem is that if I do

```
B b(A(1.0));
C c(A(1.0));
```

the class `A` is instanciated twice for `B` (two creation constructor calls).
`C::a_ptr_` is problematic. If I do :

```
B b;
C C;
{   
    A a(1.0);
    b.set(a);
    c.set(a);
}
```

I have the same problems outside the brackets.

I would like to find a way to store a pointer on `A` in `B` or `C` without
copying the class `A` too many times and without having undefined pointers.

I've found something with a `move` constructor but I've never used such. 
Any idea ? Thx !

Comment: `B` has memory leaks, and `C` has dangling pointers.  If you need to share an instance of `A`, consider using `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I forgot the delete in the class B, sorry.

Comment: `a_ptr_(&A(a))` - has disaster written all over it.

Comment: @WhozCraig : you are right, i meant somehting else... updated

Comment: @PinkFloyd now it shouldn't even *compile*, as you're constructing a non-const `A*` from a `const A*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is exactly what you need. This class is used for storing one pointer in different places. The target object will be deleted after the last `shared_ptr` pointing to it is destroyed. Since you are clearing the memory in the destructor, your classes obtain ownership of the `A` object. You can use something like this:

```
class B{
    public
        B():a_ptr_(NULL){}
        B(A * a): a_ptr_(a){ }
        ~B(){}//don't need to do anything here. 
        void set(A * a){ a_ptr_.reset(a); }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr_;
}
<...>
class C should be written in a similar manner
<...>
A * a = new a(1.0);
B b(a);
C c(a)
```

Now, if you want to make a constructor or `set` method that takes `a` by reference, you will not be able to avoid copying it. Also, in this case you can't safely take the address of this variable.

Comment: thx for your answer. I thought of this solution. I thought that the move method or something like this would allow me to pass by "reference" (rvalue) without having multiple copy.

Comment: @PinkFloyd, moving semantics does exactly what it sounds like - _moves_ something from one place to another without copying. But in your case, if you want to access `a` from different places, it will not work.

Comment: I don't necessary need to access `a` from different places, I just need to
access it via the pointer of class `B`. And it should not be destroyed as long as `B b(A(a))` exists.